# Punctuation of this: Their movements, quick and effortless; mine, lumbering and heavy

Tags: punctuation, commas, semicolons

I'm not sure how to punctuate this:

> Their movements, quick and effortless; mine, lumbering and heavy.

Maybe I got it right. Any thoughts?

Comment: It might help to see the rest of the sentence or paragraph or what not.

Answer (score 3):

This is correct semantically (and quite nicely written if I do say so myself). If you are looking for an alternative to the semicolon, you might consider an em dash, e.g.:

> Their movements, quick and effortless—mine, lumbering and heavy

Em dashes are technically less correct than a semicolon in this situation, but I feel they add a different flavor to the text. Good luck with your writing!

Answer (score 0):

> Their movements, quick and effortless; mine, lumbering and heavy.

Is not a sentence. I think it context might have been something like this:

> **We we hiking uphill:** their movements, quick and effortless; mine, lumbering and heavy.

or better,

> **We we hiking uphill:** their movements *were* quick and effortless, mine**,** lumbering and heavy.

Either way, it's a fragment.

Comment: I think you meant ‘we were’ in both your examples. But other than that, agreed. Nothing wrong with a good fragment, of course, in the right circumstances.